# Performance issues with simple calculations

Tags: c++, optimization

EDIT 2: **16% decrease in program computation time!** See bottom for calculation

---

I have written a N-body simulator, implementing the Barnes-Hut algorithm. Now I have a innocent looking function called `CheckNode`. Its simple and doesn't take long to compute, but the issue is, it gets called **millions** of times, so it takes up most of the calculation time between each frame.

I profiled the code, and this function is responsible for `84.58%` of the total calculation time, and this is with only 10K particles, when I do it with up to 10x this, this function uses a greater and greater percentage.

---

Now here is the function, with percentage of time spent on the right in the red.

[image]

---

Now there are some alarming things here, Like a simple if statement taking `9.17%` and another if statement accounting for over 20% of computation time! Is there any, even the slightest optimisation that can be done here, that would be multiplied over millions of function calls to allow my program to run faster?

EDIT:

Here is the `CalculateForceNode` function:

```
void CalculateForceNode(Body* bi, Node* bj)  //bi is being attracted to bj. 15 flops of calculation
{
    //vector from the body to the center of mass
    double vectorx = bj->CenterOfMassx - bi->posX;
    double vectory = bj->CenterOfMassy - bi->posY;

    //c^2 = a^2 + b^2 + softener^2
    double distSqr = vectorx * vectorx + vectory * vectory + Softener * Softener;

    // ivnDistCube = 1/distSqr^(3/2)
    double distSixth = distSqr * distSqr * distSqr;
    double invDistCube = 1.0f / (sqrt(distSixth));

    double Accel = (bj->TotalMass * invDistCube * _GRAV_CONST);

    bi->AccelX += vectorx * Accel;
    bi->AccelY += vectory * Accel;
}
```

EDIT 2:

**Results of optimisations**

The `CheckNode` function now takes up `82.03%` of the total computation time (measured over a 1 min 37 sec sample), as opposed to previously it took up `84.58%`.

Now logic tells that the remaining `15%` of calculation time, took the same as the remaining `18%` calculation time *of the second program*. So these identical periods (Its the same code) took `15%` of the first program, and `18%` of the second program. Letting the time to complete this other code be `x` the 1st program took `1/0.15` = `6.666x` and the second took `1/0.18` = `5.555x`. Then you can find the fraction that `5.555x` is of `6.666x` which calculates to be `~0.83` and therefor there was a (`1 - 0.83 = 0.16`) **16% decrease in program computation time!**

Comment: in your if statement, do the HasChildren check first, avoid double division and do widthSqr < distanceSqr * NodeThresholdSqr (unless this would overflow double?)... CalculateForceNode is efficient?

Comment: I think you should show us the code of CalculateForceNode() which is ~45%. About the conditions which is 23%, I think you should reverse the elements in one of them, you should use if(pNode->HasChildren == false || (withSqr / distanceSqr < nodeThresholdSqr)) instead of if(withSqr / distanceSqr < nodeThresholdSqr || pNode->HasChildren == false)

Comment: Another issue would be.. are you calling checknode more than once on each node, and does the answer change with time? It might help if you save the results so u only ever calculate the checknode for a specific node once

Comment: how did profiled? I really like the way it looks.

Comment: If I reverse the statements in the if statement, then does it ignore the second one if the first one is true?

Comment: @Nick I used `AMD Code XL` to profile the code

Comment: Swapping the elements doesn’t help only to avoid useless calculation but it could also reduce waiting: The expression `widthSqr / distanceSqr < nodeThresholdSqr` needs the results of previous statements. When the program comes to the line, they may be still being computed in the [pipeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_pipeline), so the independent check for `pNode->HasChildren` can be done in the meantime.

Comment: double invDistCube = 1.0f / (sqrt(distSixth)); this line must take long time. There is a lot of sqrt approximation which are a lot faster than the real one. You should search for this.

Comment: if possible, replace division with multiplication. also replace sqrt with multiplication - i think you can not do it in your case, but you know your algoritm better.

Comment: And how do you propose replacing sqrt with a multiplication, thats just not possible

Comment: @KierenPearson it would be nice of you to let us know which of the suggestions here work best. I'm sure we're all eager to find out!

Comment: for the inverse square root in CalculateForceNode, this fast aproximation (originating from quake3 source code) might be of interest to you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root#Overview_of_the_code

Comment: @kieren if (sqrt(x) > 6) may become if (x > 6 * 6)

Comment: Yes, that was actialy used in the check node function where I check `if (widthSqr / distanceSqr < NodeThresholdSq)` rather than `(width / distance < NodeThreshold)` where I would sqrt() on the distance, now I dont have to, but the only other sqrt left I need the exact value of it, not a relation

Comment: cool. i m on mobile and is bit difficult to follow exact code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First thing I would try is to reverse the elements in one of your conditions, replace:

```
if(withSqr / distanceSqr < nodeThresholdSqr || pNode->HasChildren == false)
```

with:

```
if(pNode->HasChildren == false || (withSqr / distanceSqr < nodeThresholdSqr))
```

If the first part of the condition is true `pNode->HasChildren == false` than the second one `(withSqr / distanceSqr < nodeThresholdSqr)` will never be executed (read: evaluated). Checking simple condition is much faster than operations on floating point numbers (division in your case). You can even take it to the next level: *do you need to compute the `distanceSqr` AT ALL when `pNode->HasChildren == false` ?

EDIT: even better:

```
if(pNode->HasChildren == false)
{
    CalculateForceNode(pBody,pNode);
}
else
{
    double distanceSqr = ((diffX * diffX) + (diffY * diffY));
    double withSqr     = pNode->width * pNode->width;
    if(withSqr / distanceSqr < nodeThresholdSqr)
    {
        CalculateForceNode(pBody,pNode);
    }
    else
    {//if not, repeat function with child
        if(pNode->Child[0]->Bodies.size() > 0)
            CheckNode(pNode->Child[0],pBody);
        //..... - all the rest of your code
    }
}
```

Comment: No I don't need to calculate it if `HasChildren` is false. So should I check if `HasChildren` is true, and only if is **is true**, then check `(withSqr / distanceSqr < nodeThresholdSqr)`?

Comment: no. george's arrangement will do that for you. which is why its faster. also consider replacing the division with multiplication as per my comment. To be clear, if HasChildren is false the IF statement returns true without calculating the second part.

Comment: This is assuming that the compiler can't do the re-ordering himself, which I would find somewhat odd.

Comment: @Puppy - I agree, but it does not hurt, and anyway he should experiment with many solutions (and his compiler)

Answer (score 3):

Profiling based on time spent is not enough, you need to know what was this time spent in - in other words use a more advanced profiler.

Also you don't mention any information about compiler or platform you are using.

For the if statement that is using 9% of the time, I don't think it is spent in the comparison, it is spent in fetching data. You have multiple levels of indirection (accessing data using pointer that takes you to another pointer and so on). This is bad for caching and branch prediction, and I guess you are spending time fetching data from memory or doing useless calculations because of branch miss prediction, not doing the actual comparison.

another note that I noticed: if (pNode->HasChildren == false) then you don't need all the calculations you made to find widthSqr. I think you should restructure your logic to check for this first, if the condition is false then you can can calculate widthSqr and continue your logic.

Comment: I used Intel's vTune before and it provided detailed info.

Comment: If I remember correctly It was good and full featured. You can search for any other cheaper profiler that gives info on branch prediction and cache hits and misses. This will be one step forward in analyzing your code's performance.

Answer (score 2):

- First you should `inline` function `Bodies.size()` or access `size` directly so there is no overhead with function calling (it takes time to push all needed information to stack and pop it off).
- I don't see all the code, but it looks like you can precalculate `widthSqr`. It can be calculated when the `width` is assigned not in the function.
- You are using a lot of pointers here and it looks like your structures are scattered all over the memory. This will generate a lot CPU cache misses. Make sure that all the data needed for computation are in one, long, continuous and compact memory area.
- In `CalculateForceNode` check if `Softener*Softener` can be precalculated. `sqrt` function is very time consuming. `sqrt` algorithm is iterative so you can sacrifice accuracy for speed by doing less iterations or you can use Look up tables.
- You are doing the same calculations twice in `CalculateForceNode`.

  ```
  void CalculateForceNode(Body* bi, Node* bj) 
      {
          //vector from the body to the center of mass
          double vectorx = bj->CenterOfMassx - bi->posX;
          double vectory = bj->CenterOfMassy - bi->posY;

          //c^2 = a^2 + b^2 + softener^2
          double distSqr = vectorx * vectorx + vectory * vectory...
  ```

`vectorx,vectory and distSqr` were already calulated in `CheckNode` as `diffX, diffY and distanceSqr`. Manually inline whole function `CalculateForceNode`.

Comment: `inline` is largely redundant these days - the compiler can and will choose to ignore you if it knows better :)

Comment: Ignore explicit `inline`? I don't think so.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/35432/inline-functions-in-c-whats-the-point

Comment: precalculating widthSqr will have no effect, because it only gets calculated once per node anyways, and each frame all the nodes reset, and are recalculated.

Comment: Explanation about `inline` is very vague, really. You give me this to convince me? Anyway, it looks like he is accessing some member `size` so he can do it directly without function.

Answer (score 2):

Since the function is called a lot of times you should get rid of the overhead of calling `CalculateForceNode(...)` by manually inlining the code. One you do this you will notice other tricks to apply:

```
void CheckNode(Node* pNode, Body* pBody)
{    
    double diffX = (pNode->CenterOfMass - pBody->posX);
    double diffY = (pNode->CenterOfMass - pBody->posY);

    double distanceSqr = ((diffX * diffX) + (diffY * diffY));
    double widthSqr = pNode->width * pNode->width;

    if (widthSqr / distanceSqr < NodeThresholdSqr || pNode->hasChildren == false)
    {       
        //vector from the body to the center of mass
        double vectorx = pNode->CenterOfMassx - pBody->posX;
        double vectory = pNode->CenterOfMassy - pBody->posY;

        //c^2 = a^2 + b^2 + softener^2
        double distSqr = vectorx * vectorx + vectory * vectory + Softener * Softener;

        // ivnDistCube = 1/distSqr^(3/2)
        double distSixth = distSqr * distSqr * distSqr;
        double invDistCube = 1.0f / (sqrt(distSixth));

        double Accel = (pNode->TotalMass * invDistCube * _GRAV_CONST);

        pBody->AccelX += vectorx * Accel;
        pBody->AccelY += vectory * Accel;
    }
    else
    {
       CheckChildren(pNode, pBody);
    }

}
```

Now you can see that `diffX = vectorx`, `diffY = vectory`, `distSqr = distanceSqr*Softner*Softner`. Reusing some of the calculation already made  and precomputing whatever is possible should save you some cycles:

```
void CheckNode(Node* pNode, Body* pBody)
{    
    double diffX = (pNode->CenterOfMass - pBody->posX);
    double diffY = (pNode->CenterOfMass - pBody->posY);

    double distanceSqr = ((diffX * diffX) + (diffY * diffY));
    double widthSqr = pNode->width * pNode->width;
    double SoftnerSq = Softener * Softener;  //precompute this value

    if (widthSqr / distanceSqr < NodeThresholdSqr || pNode->hasChildren == false)
    { 
        //c^2 = a^2 + b^2 + softener^2
        double distSqr = distanceSqr + SoftnerSq;

        // ivnDistCube = 1/distSqr^(3/2)
        double distSixth = distSqr * distSqr * distSqr;
        double invDistCube = 1.0f / (sqrt(distSixth));

        double Accel = (pNode->TotalMass * invDistCube * _GRAV_CONST);

        pBody->AccelX += diffX * Accel;
        pBody->AccelY += diffY * Accel;
    }
    else
    {
       CheckChildren(pNode, pBody);
    }

}
```

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Swap your if statement around and move all your calculations inside the `pNode->hasChildren == false` part:

```
void CheckChildren(Node* pNode, Body* pBody)
{
    if (pNode->Child[0]->Bodies.size() > 0)
        CheckNode(...
}

void CheckNode(Node* pNode, Body* pBody)
{
    if (pNode->hasChildren != false)
    {
        double diffX = (pNode->CenterOfMass - pBody->posX);
        double diffY = (pNode->CenterOfMass - pBody->posY);

        double distanceSqr = ((diffX * diffX) + (diffY * diffY));
        double widthSqr = pNode->width * pNode->width;

        if (widthSqr / distanceSqr < NodeThresholdSqr)
        {
            CalculateForceNode(pBody, pNode);
        }
        else
        {
            CheckChildren(pNode, pBody);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        CheckChildren(pNode, pBody);
    }
}
```